# Will user be able to read data before transaction complete

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I am using code like

```
 $this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

same table is used for other read purpose. I don't want other user to read the records until i have finished writing all records. Will transactions take care of it?

Comment: Do you use InnoDB, MyISAM or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the storage engine from the table support transactions it does.

If you have MyISAM (or mixed) tables you can use LOCK TABLES instead.

```
LOCK TABLES
    table1 WRITE,
    table2 WRITE
```

You'll have to lock all the tables you want to query within the 'transaction'
After you're done use UNLOCK TABLES